# money_format smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Buenas, quisiera poder convertir esta cifra:

23785638.83 a 23.785.638,83

en smarty estaba pensando usar money_format pero me sale entero, si me pueden ayudar les agradeceria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/es/language.modifier.string.format.tpl) de `SMARTY`, debería ser:

**`*.php:`** `$smarty->assign( 'number', 23785638.83 );`

**`*.tpl:`**  `{$number|number_format:2:",":"."}`

Resultado: `23.785.638,83`

Comment: funciona como un filtro, que interesante

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con la funcion `number_format` referencia http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php

de acuerdo a la especificacion:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

llegamos a la conclucion:

```
 <?php
    echo number_format( 23785638.83, 2, ",", "." );
    ?>
```

ejemplo funcionando: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f820002d7a4d1b6f8ff6d0cc258f2fc1331a8246